# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 1 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1915 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the first note:

[image]

This is the transcribed text:

> El 13 de Sepre (Septiembre) se incorporó al puesto de Algaidilla,
> donde fue destinado por el Señor 1ª Jefe de la Comandancia.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I think I have transcribed it correctly.

---

#### Translation

I have the following translation:

> On the 13th of September he joined the post of Algaidilla, where he
> was assigned by the 1st Chief of the Command.
>
> The Major Commander

I tried to find a link to the Civil Guard office for the town **Algaidilla**. But I couldn't find one. I am a little confused though. On Google Maps it seems that this is a place in **Estepa**.

- Clarification about **Algaidilla** where he was posted would be appreciated.
- Also, how high up the chain would he be as **1st Chief of the Command**?

---

#### Update

I have found a [Puesto de Estepa](https://www.guardiacivil.es/es/institucional/directorio/sevilla/puesto_de_estepa.html) but not for Algaidilla.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 2 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39478/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 3 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39481/28260)

Comment: I have only found Algaidilla as a private property located near Estepa now containing a rural hotel. The brief description of its history does not show any mention of a Guardia Civil post. http://www.destinosevillarural.com/es/recursos/377/cortijo-la-algaidilla It's not rare that you find no mention of it in the current records of the Guardia Civil, many posts located in small towns have been closed since 1915 due to people leaving to find a better life in capitals.

Comment: You can use the [search engine of the Statistical and Cartographic Institute of Andalusia](http://www.ideandalucia.es/nomenclator/buscador.jsp?lang=eng) to search for locations. Algaidilla, as @RubioRic mentioned, could probably be a "Cortijo" located [here](https://goo.gl/maps/eeeBPPVdT2quSpv36), between Roda and Estepa.