# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 2 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1915 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the second note (split over 2 pages):

[image]

[image]

Again, I find this find of handwriting on the difficult side to read. But I have managed to transcribe some of it I think. So far I have:

> Por Real Orden manneria del ministerio de la observación fecha 21 de
> Agosto, publicara en el semanario oficial del Cuerpo xxx de 1º de
> Septiembre, este dieron a gracias por en distinginor xxx xxx a xxx la
> xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx durante xx meses de xxx, xxx y xxx.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

As always, thank you for your help with transcribing and translation.

---

#### Update

In the answer it refers to the number 405. I think that is correct because the 5 is also quite ornate here at the top left of the page:

[image]

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39477/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 3 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39481/28260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por Real Orden **manuscrita** del **Ministerio de la Gobernación** fecha 21 de Agosto, **publicada** en el Semanario Oficial del Cuerpo n° 405 de 1º de Septiembre, **se le** dieron **las** gracias por **su distinguido comportamiento** **y plausible celo** **al cumplir la misión de vigilancia y defensa que se le encomendara** durante **los** meses de **Junio, Julio** y **Agosto**.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

- By handwritten Royal Order of the [Ministry of Governance](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministerio_de_la_Gobernaci%C3%B3n_(Espa%C3%B1a)) on August 21, published in the Official Weekly Report of the Corps number 405 of September 1, he was thanked for his distinguished behavior and commendable zeal when completing the mission of watching and defending that was assigned to him during the months of June, July and August.

Of course, the number (405) may be wrong. The expression "plausible celo" sounds weird to me but, [according to CORDE](https://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=plausible%20celo&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) and [BNE's *Hemeroteca Digital*](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=%22plausible%20celo%22&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&view=&lang=es), it seems to have been used in the past to commend someone's efforts or zeal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and extra info. I’ll review it in the morning.

Comment: Great work. I think that it's "encomendara" instead of "encomendaba"

Comment: What do you think if we were to change **plausible** to **outstanding**?

Comment: Also, I updated my question with a screenshot of the 1915 handwriting at the top left of the page. So I think that 405 is most likely correct.

Comment: Please let me know if I need to change **encomendaba**.

Comment: Hmm, difficult. Both "encomendara"  and "encomendaba" would be grammatically correct, but maybe it does look more like an "r". I changed that.

Comment: I wonder what was going on at the time for those three months in that area? Hhm!!

Answer (score 2):

In relation with the translation of **plausible** ...

According to the DLE

> [plausible](https://dle.rae.es/plausible)
>
> 1. adj. Digno o merecedor de aplauso.

In English it would be

> Worthy of applause

Originally that was the meaning of [plausible](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plausible) in English according to the Oxford Dictionary

> Origin Mid 16th century (also in the sense ‘deserving applause or
> approval’): from Latin plausibilis, from plaus- ‘applauded’, from the
> verb plaudere.

But it seems to have lost that sense nowadays.

Instead of [outstanding](https://www.lexico.com/definition/outstanding) (meaning: Exceptionally good), that would be translated as **sobresaliente** in Spanish, I think that **laudable** is a better choice in this case.

> [laudable](https://www.lexico.com/definition/laudable) 
> (of an action, idea, or aim) deserving praise and
> commendation.

Comment: Ok. I get you. I suppose if it were me I would say commendable as opposed to laudable. But I will use your seg gestión here. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Commendable seems to be a synonym of laudable. Both work perfectly in this context.