# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 3 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1915 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the third note:
[image]

I think I have managed to trabscribe this note correctly. See what you think:

> Finió el año prestando en servicio en el puesto de Algaidilla.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

#### Translation

The above translates as:

> He ended the year on duty at the Algaidilla post.
>
> The Major Commander

See if you agree. Thanks!

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39477/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1915 (note 2 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39478/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the translation but the transcription should be

> Finió el año prestando **sus servicios** en el puesto de Algaidilla.
> El Comandante Mayor

---

Bonus:
There is a town in the province of Málaga named [Villanueva de Algaidas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villanueva_de_Algaidas). It's not related with the place in Seville named Algaidilla (Little Algaida) apart from sharing the same word taken from ancient arab **algaida**.

According to the DLE

> algaida
>
> 1. adj. And. Cubierto de ramas o paja. (*Covered by branches or straw*)

Just a curiosity.

Comment: Thanks. That refinement (now made at my end) produces a slightly different translation: *He ended the year serving at the Algaidilla post.* I suppose this latter translation is more accurate?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, I think so.